# WPF: How to change behavior at runtime?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, behavior

I'm designing UI in WPF for logic circuit simulator. I want my application to support various behaviors depending on current operation mode like selection mode (rubberband selection), component placing mode, wiring mode, interaction mode etc. I thought about using state pattern in my ViewModel and encapsulating the behaviors in states corresponding to operation modes.

My trouble is reflecting this changes in the View. I want each mode to subscribe to different mouse events (selection is mouse down, mouse move, mouse up; placing is mouse enter, mouse move, mouse leave). Can I encapsulate this in generic behaviors and then somehow switch behaviors at runtime? Should I use attached properties for it? Or maybe custom control? What's the MVVM way of doing this?

Comment: There are no subscribing to mouse events in wpf :) Instead you bind to commands :)

Comment: uiElement.MouseLeftButtonDown += (sender, eventArgs) => { /*code*/ };
Can be done from within behavior or helper class to be more mvvm. Still I don't know what's the best way to change it at runtime.
But thanks anyway :)

Comment: I told you already the best way is Commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the different behaviours linked to mouse events only and the XAML of UserControl is always the same?

If the answer is yes then you can implements a single behaviour attached to all mouse events you want to manage in all scenarios and store the current scenario inside a variable of the UserControl.

Doing so, your custom behaviour can decide to call or not to call a particular `ICommand`, basing on the value of the variable of the UserControl that indicates the current scenario.

Comment: That should do the trick most of the time. Also, what would you suggest if change of the state was linked to change in XAML?

Comment: In that scenario you can use some 'DataTemplate' and then switch among them using 'DataTrigger' bind to a property that indicates the current scenario